# AXWindowsMediaPlayer not finding embedded resource MP3

Tags: c#, .net, audio, media

I have a embedded resource file (MP3 to be exact) that plays a short boop. I wanted it for easy transport of the file since I have a lot more of them that I'm looking to add in.

When I try to play it, WMP just says it cannot find the file.
I'm using `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"ultraelecguitar.Properties.Resources.pitchedbeep";` to access it. It is added in the resource manager, and marked as a embedded resource. When I run my program with the file in the directory, it works just fine. When I don't, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save resource as temporary file then you could provide it's path as url.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wmp.URL = CreateTempFileFromResource("ConsoleApplication1.mp3.somefile.mp3");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static string CreateTempFileFromResource(string resourceName)
    {
        var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName() + Path.GetExtension(resourceName);
        using (var resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (var tempFileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            resourceStream.CopyTo(tempFileStream);
        }
        return tempFilePath;
    }
```